# Java thread is repeating the swing form

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am using java threads to manage multiple (3) programs concurrently.
1 is for Java swing form(draws UI for input), 1 is for setting an icon at systemtray (launchs immediate after taking input from UI), and 1 is for Processing inputs and reflect it to the SystemTray icon (in form of a popup message to that Tray Icon).

Earlier, I tried without separate Threads but the problem I was facing is "if the execution control once goes forward (from UI to next Process) where some repetitive task are performed using thread.sleep() method (that holds the control actually for entire time).Hence the earlier forms(UI) remains unresponsive (we cant even close the form that time).

So, I thought to implement separate threads for each of three. But as soon as I try to launch The Form (UI), it goes repetitive in infinite loop actually.

Here, is the code:

```
 public class ImprovedImplementation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Main thread is started...");  
    new LauncherUI();        
    }

 }

class LauncherUI implements Runnable {

private JFrame mainFrame;
private JLabel headerLabel;
private JLabel statusLabel;
private JPanel controlPanel;

String textFieldValue = null;

Thread launcher ;
LauncherUI()
 { 
  prepareGUI();
  launcher = new Thread(this, "Launcher Thread");
  System.out.println("launcher thread created" + launcher);
  launcher.start();
  }
  public void run()
  {
  try
  {      
    LauncherUI swingControlDemo = new LauncherUI();
    swingControlDemo.showEventDemo();    
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("launcher thread interrupted");
  }
  System.out.println("launcher run is over" );
 }   

private void prepareGUI() {

    mainFrame.setSize(450, 400);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
    statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);

    statusLabel.setSize(350, 100);
    mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
    mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
    mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
}

private void showEventDemo() {
    headerLabel.setText("Welcome to the Web Server Tracking System !!");
    headerLabel.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));

    JLabel l = new JLabel();
    l.setText("Enter All (Servers) URLs separated by a comma ( , ) :");
    l.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel();
    l2.setText("[for example: google.com,wikipedia.org,sjsu.edu]");
    l2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    JTextField txt = new JTextField(30);

    JButton submitButton = new JButton("Start Tracking");
    JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Close");

    submitButton.setActionCommand("Start");
    cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");

    submitButton.addActionListener(new ButtonClickListener());
    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            textFieldValue = txt.getText();
        // textFieldValue="Hello";
            // .... do some operation on value ...
        }
    });
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ButtonClickListener());

    controlPanel.add(l);
    controlPanel.add(l2);
    controlPanel.add(txt);
    controlPanel.add(submitButton);
    controlPanel.add(cancelButton);

    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

}

private class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Start")) {
            if (textFieldValue.equals("") || textFieldValue.indexOf(".") == -1) {
                statusLabel.setText("Please Enter Some Server Urls, Before Start Tracking.");
                if (textFieldValue.indexOf(".") == -1 && !textFieldValue.equals("")) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Please Enter Valid Urls.");
                }
                statusLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
            } else {
                StringTokenizer urlValues = new StringTokenizer(textFieldValue, ",");
                Vector v = new Vector();
                while (urlValues.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String token = urlValues.nextToken();
                    v.add(token);
                }
                String[] urlStrArray = (String[]) v.toArray(new String[v.size()]);
                System.out.println("Took following URLS from the User:");
                for(int m=0; m < urlStrArray.length;m++){
                    System.out.println(urlStrArray[m]);
                }
                statusLabel.setText("Tracking is started . . .  it's pinned in your System Tray ( Task bar ).");
                statusLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone Help me out.
It would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `main()` does a `new LauncherUI()`.

Your LauncherUI constructor calls `start()` on a `Runnable`; the `run()` method calls `new LauncherUI()`.  That constructor calls `start()`, repeating the process; classic endless loop.

Comment: Thanks... now I can proceed further. Thanks a lot.